# using constexpr with static in circular initialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I tried to understand how to use constexpr from different sources. But I have a problem that I want to convert the program below to use constexpr instead of const. This program is template of my main program.

```
class B;

class A{
public:
constexpr A(int){}
const static B& obj;
};

class B:A{
public:
    constexpr B(int x):A(x){}
    const static B& obj;
};

const B& A::obj=B(10);
const B& B::obj=B(20);
```

In last line I want to use constexpr to ensure that this obj variable is present at compile time and thus reduce my code size and optimize but according to standards constexpr can't be used. And it gives error about multiple declarations. And if I change the const in class A then initialization is must.I want to use obj variable in constexpr function and since obj is not present in compile time error occure. I am asking how can I solve the problem because if this cannot be done then probably the optimization of code is affected by 15% thats really huge.

Comment: Do you need it in class `A` and not `B`

Comment: actually every class must be having obj as unique id.

Comment: [Compiles as written](https://rextester.com/DWUOJ71527) for me.

Comment: “In last line”… you actually want `A::obj` to be `constexpr` *too*, right?

Comment: Including the code that *doesn't* work when you tried it can be illuminating.

Comment: I tried in gcc trunk versions

Comment: I also checked the standards. They say constexpr with static needs to be initialized as soon as they are made that means in class A if I change const to constexpr it will not compile because B is not defined and in example given by P.W. the obj is still const not constexpr. Thus still give error when I do static_assert.

Answer (score 1):

As `constexpr` applies the const-ness to the object defined, you can use `constexpr` before `const` in the last line or the last two lines (if that's what you really want) like this.

```
constexpr const B& A::obj=B(10);
constexpr const B& B::obj=B(20);
```

This works. See compiled demo [here](https://rextester.com/FOSUOQ73646).

Comment: class B;

class A{
public:
constexpr A(int y):x(y){}
    int x;
    const static B& obj;
};

class B:A{
public:
    constexpr B(int x):A(x){}
    const static B& obj;
    constexpr friend bool operator==(const B a,const B b){
        return a.x==b.x;
    }
};

constexpr const B& A::obj=B(10);
constexpr const B& B::obj=B(20);

int main()
{
    constexpr B y=10;
    static_assert(A::obj==y);
}

Comment: this code is in error since A::obj is not constexpr it is still linked in runtime.

Comment: The code you have provided in the comment does not compile and it is not due to the failure of `static_assert`

Comment: the code I provide is  not working will be giving error that A::obj is not constexpr that means the type of obj is const not constexpr.